# What happens if Node process itself is busy

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

May be this question is easy but I just want to know **what happens when the Node Js process itself is busy with some process**, then what happens to other processes.

### So here is my scenario.

I have 2 servers

1. AppServer on port 3000
2. JobServer on port 5000

Both are running on a machine with **2 core** and in clustered mode. So as per my understanding there would be **2 instances of AppServer and 2 instances of JobServer** and internally **Node js load balances** to which instance it needs to call(correct me if I am wrong). This setup is behind and ELB also.

So from outside I call the server as:

```
<ELB_URL>/<something>/1 ---> this goes to AppServer.js
<ELB_URL>/<something>/2 ---> this goes to JobServer.js
```

**Case 1** Now lets suppose that, for some request, the AppServer is going 100% CPU usage. And at that time the JobServer also stops working or I should say gets blocked.

Now since the AppServer is different then JobServer, why JobServer is not responding at all, I mean it should be working, right?

**Case 2** Or if I take the **scenario of Chrome** which is also **built over V8 Engine** that is the **basis of NodeJs**, if one tab is blocked it blocks other tabs also, so if I consider **1 tab as 1 server** & if AppServer is blocked it will block the JobServer obviously.

1. So if 1 is correct that blocking JobServer is wrong then why it is happening?
2. And if case 2 is correct then I have an answer why JobServer is getting blocked.

Please give your opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One physical (or virtual) server machine is running both your app servers. If one app causes the hardware to reach its capacity (RAM, CPU, etc.), it will essentially "block" the other app server or render it very slow and unresponsive. That is because the other app is relying on the same hardware resources.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

In node.js, regardless of how may CPU/Cores you have there is only 1 single event queue. That means that if the event that is currently being processed is stuck the whole app is stuck.

To overcome this you need to run 2 distinct node.js processes, one per server.

Comment: Ok thanks @Toto I will change the design and as per this the chrome scenario is the one that is being applied on server side as well. Nice to know that. (+1)